# java regex read property, what is different double parentheses

Tags: java, regex

form: column1 = emp_no
extract:
key: column1
value: emp_no

first code:

```
String p1 = "column1 = emp_no";

String propertyRegexp = "^\\s*(\\w+)\\s*=\\s*(\\w+)\\s*$";

Pattern pattern = Pattern.compile(propertyRegexp);
Matcher matcher = pattern.matcher(p1);
System.out.println("groupCount: " + matcher.groupCount());
if(matcher.matches()) {
    for(int i = 0; i < matcher.groupCount(); i++) {
        System.out.println(i + ": " + matcher.group(i));    
    }
}
```

first result:

```
groupCount: 2
0: column1 = emp_no
1: column1
```

It is not possible to find a second result.
The second brackets change to double parentheses.

second code:

```
String p1 = "column1 = emp_no";

String propertyRegexp = "^\\s*(\\w+)\\s*=\\s*((\\w+))\\s*$";

Pattern pattern = Pattern.compile(propertyRegexp);
Matcher matcher = pattern.matcher(p1);
System.out.println("groupCount: " + matcher.groupCount());
if(matcher.matches()) {
    for(int i = 0; i < matcher.groupCount(); i++) {
        System.out.println(i + ": " + matcher.group(i));    
    }
}
```

second result:

```
groupCount: 3
0: column1 = emp_no
1: column1
2: emp_no
```

I want results are output.
What is different regex in first and second code?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Change your code to.

```
String p1 = "column1 = emp_no";

String propertyRegexp = "^\\s*(\\w+)\\s*=\\s*(\\w+)\\s*$";

Pattern pattern = Pattern.compile(propertyRegexp);
Matcher matcher = pattern.matcher(p1);
System.out.println("groupCount: " + matcher.groupCount());
if(matcher.matches()) {
    for(int i = 1; i <= matcher.groupCount(); i++) {  //see the changes
        System.out.println(i + ": " + matcher.group(i));    
    }
}
```

0th group always contains the entire matched string.

Actual groups start from index 1

Check out this **[live demo](http://ideone.com/Ah00XT)**

Answer (score 2):

Groups in regex are indexed from 0, but group 0 is added by regex engine automatically to represent entire match. Your groups are indexed as `1` and `2`.

So your first attempt was almost correct, you should simply change loop from

```
for(int i = 0; i < matcher.groupCount(); i++) {
```

to

```
for(int i = 1; i <= matcher.groupCount(); i++) {
//          ^     ^
```

You can read more about groups at official Java tutorual about regex https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/essential/regex/groups.html
where we can find example showing how groups are numbered:

> ...capturing groups are numbered by counting their opening parentheses from left to right. In the expression `((A)(B(C)))`, for example, there are four such groups:
>
> 1. `((A)(B(C)))`
> 2. `(A)`
> 3. `(B(C))`
> 4. `(C)`
>
> ...
> There is also a special group, group 0, which always represents the entire expression.